# Fatal Exception With APWidgets (Processing 3.0)

Tags: android, processing

I'm trying to use APWidgets for some basic Android buttons with Processing, but creating an APWidgetContainer throws the error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: Animation Thread Process: processing.test.experiment, PID: 12094 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: processing.core.PApplet.runOnUiThread

My code is just:

```
import apwidgets.*;

APWidgetContainer widgetContainer;

void setup() {
}

void draw() { 
    widgetContainer = new APWidgetContainer(this);
}
```

Does anyone have a solution, or know why this is happening?

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/13360/fatal-exception-with-apwidgets

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if APWidgets plays ball with the latest version of Processing? A lot of libraries aren't updated for Processing 3. Also why are you creating a new instance of APWidgetContatiner in the draw loop? I'm hardly familiar with the library but presumably you want to do that in setup() ?